# Failed upgrade to php 7 on CentOS 7

Tags: php, upgrade, centos7

I was trying to upgrade php 5.4 to 7 on my CentOS 7 using this toutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-centos-7

And I made this:

```
sudo yum remove php-cli mod_php php-common
```

[erased everything - done]

```
sudo yum install mod_php70u php70u-cli php70u-mysqlnd
```

"nothing to do"

All my websites are: 502 Bad Gateway / nginx

In Plesk I see this:

> New configuration files for the Apache web server were not created due to the errors in configuration templates: 
>   [Sun Jul 10 20:52:21.734150 2016] [so:warn] [pid 11833] AH01574: module actions_module is already loaded, skipping
>  
>   [Sun Jul 10 20:52:21.735241 2016] [so:warn] [pid 11833] AH01574: module headers_module is already loaded, skipping [Sun Jul 10 20:52:21.735398 2016] [so:warn] [pid 11833] AH01574: module logio_module is already loaded, skipping 
>   [Sun Jul 10 20:52:21.735945 2016] [so:warn] [pid 11833] AH01574: module suexec_module is already loaded, skipping AH00526: Syntax error on line 33 of /etc/httpd/conf/plesk.conf.d/roundcube.conf: Wrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper cannot be accessed: (2)No such file or directory . Detailed error descriptions were sent to you by email. Please resolve the issues and click here to generate broken configuration files once again or here to generate all configuration files. See the details in Configuration Troubleshooter

Please help.

Comment: This is more a question about your server configuration than coding. I'd try serverfault, http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: NB: Server Fault does *not* take questions about server administration panels like Plesk.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **NGINX.** as web server this works. instructions to apache are very similar. the part that changes is the last part.

I had to set up servers with NGINX/APACHE that support and array of **PHP** versions (from 5.3 to php7).

the server that we currently use is NGINX (has better performance and lower memory footprint)

In order to have multiple versions I compile PHP from the source and make listen the php process in a 127.0.0.1:port

```
ex: fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9053; (php53)
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9054; (php54)
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9055; (php55)
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9056; (php56)
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9070; (php57)
```

you will need to install all depedencies in order to compile **PHP from source:**

```
yum update -y
yum install epel-release -y    
yum update -y    
yum group install "Development Tools" -y

yum install wget curl nano libmcrypt-devel bzip2-devel curl-devel db4-devel libjpeg-devel libpng-devel libXpm-devel gmp-devel libc-client-devel openldap-devel unixODBC-devel postgresql-devel sqlite-devel net-snmp-devel libxslt-devel pcre-devel mysql-devel postgresql-devel libxslt-devel mariadb-client freetype-devel.x86_64 libxml2-devel -y

yum install httpd php php-xml php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-pdo -y 

yum install php-devel php-pear mysql-devel httpd-devel -y
```

Then you will need to download the desired php version.
Dowload PHP7 into the /opt/ folder of the server.

http://php.net/get/php-7.0.8.tar.gz/from/a/mirror

(In the server, I prefer to download and compile PHP in the /opt/ folder.)

```
cd /opt/
```

Extract the source:

```
tar xzvf php-7.0.*.tar.gz (the version you download)
```

cd into the php folder:

```
cd php-7.0.8/
```

Configure php.

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/php7 --with-pdo-pgsql --with-zlib-dir --with-freetype-dir --enable-mbstring --with-libxml-dir=/usr --enable-soap --enable-calendar --with-curl --with-mcrypt --with-zlib --with-gd --with-pgsql --disable-rpath --enable-inline-optimization --with-bz2 --with-zlib --enable-sockets --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-pcntl --enable-mbregex --enable-exif --enable-bcmath --with-mhash --enable-zip --with-pcre-regex  --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysqli --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-openssl --with-fpm-user=apache --with-fpm-group=apache --with-libdir=lib64     --enable-ftp --with-kerberos --with-gettext --with-xmlrpc --with-xsl --enable-opcache --enable-fpm
```

then:

```
 make && make install
    cd sapi/fpm
    #create start/stop php-php script
    cp init.d.php-fpm /etc/init.d/php7
    #give perms
    chmod 775 /etc/init.d/php7
    #move php-fpm configuration file to right location
    mv /opt/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf.default /opt/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf 
    mv /opt/php7/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf.default /opt/php7/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
    #configure php-fpm to listen to 9070 port
    sed -i 's/^listen =.*/listen = 127.0.0.1:9070/' /opt/php7/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
   #copy php.ini file to right location
    cp /opt/php-7.0.8/php.ini-production /opt/php7/lib/php.ini
    #Give perms
    chmod 777 /opt/php7/lib/php.ini    
    # start PHP7 automatically
    chkconfig --add php7
    chkconfig --level 345 php7 on
```

Then create the **NGINX** configuration file.

```
server {
    listen  80;

    server_name test.com www.test.com;

    location / {
        root  /var/www/html/7;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }       

     location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /var/www/html/7;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9070;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }



}
```

Finally:

```
service nginx stop
service nginx start
```

And you are ready to go...
hope this helps.
Detailed info: https://github.com/dferrans/Centos-7-nginx-stack-multiple-php

Comment: Hey!,Thank you for your advice! I really appreciate your efforts however I restored my system and now all works well. I didn't know that Plesk offer switch php  version function for every website so it's a convenient functionality. Now I can freely switch from whole range php versions for all my website separately. But thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you already install all the RPMs? If so, try this:

```
yum install php70u php70u-fpm php70u-fpm-nginx php70u-mbstring php70u-json -y
```